# Can't get PostgreSQL to run in Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, postgresql, apt, debian-lenny

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL 8.3 on Debian Lenny (kernel 2.6.26-2-686) using the package manager:

> sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.3
>   postgresql-client-8.3
>   postgresql-contrib-8.3
>   postgresql-common

When deploying the package postgresql-common, the following warning is displayed:

> supported_versions: WARNING: Unknown
>   Debian release: 5.0.4

I wonder if this is related to the problem I describe below.

Next I try to launch the database server but it doesn't have any effect, neither any logs are generated.

> sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 start

Does anybody have a clue of what might be going on?

**UPDATE**: These are the contents of sources.list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/lenny/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/lenny/updates main contrib
deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib 
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

**WORKAROUND**: Thanks to @lg for pointing out that this particular package is buggy. A possible workaround is to install PostgreSQL 8.4 from the Debian backports repository:

Added the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

> deb http://www.backports.org/debian
>   lenny-backports main contrib non-free

And executed:

```
apt-get install debian-backports-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get -t lenny-backports install postgresql-8.4
```

The server then starts up automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=509144), it is solved from version 95, but you are installing the stable version(94).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I finally installed it from the backports.

Answer (score 0):

Which repository are you using? I think you are installing a wrong version postgresql package.

Comment: @lg: thanks for the answer, just updated the question with the repository sources